# Where would I add my delete in this code where i used the new operator for the queue variable

Tags: c++

```
class Queue
{
 int size;
 int *queue;

public:
 Queue()
 {
     size = 0;
   // im talking about this new operator that i added
     queue = new int[100];
 }
 void remove()
 {
     if (size == 0)
     {
         cout << "Queue is empty" << endl;
         return;
     }
     else
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
         {
             queue[i] = queue[i + 1];
         }
         size--;
     }
 }
 void print()
 {
     if (size == 0)
     {
         cout << "Queue is empty" << endl;
         return;
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
     {
         cout << queue[i] << " <- ";
     }
     cout << endl;
 }

 void add(int a);
};
void Queue::add(int a)
{
 queue[size] = a;
 size++;
}
```

I want to know if the int *queue I used will need a delete and where I would put it since I used a new operator. I dont know if I should use the delete operator or if I shouldn't. Please help.

Comment: you should read about the [rule of 3/5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), because you need more than a single `delete` to manage a raw pointer as class member. Then you should read about the rule of 0 and use a `std::vector` instead of the raw pointer

Comment: You should do `int queue[100]` instead. Why use dynamic memory if the number of elements is fixed anyways?

Comment: Also note that you will actually [need a `delete []`](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#allocate-array), since you are using `new[]`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number The delete should only be in the destructor. The copy/move semantics should use the destructor to free up resources. (i.e. move and swap)

Comment: @Mestskon ok, doesnt change the message of my comment. Deleting the array only in the destructor isnt sufficient, OP needs to take care of rule of 3/5

Comment: This code doesn't work because there is no variable outside the class called `queue`

Comment: And the question is not where but rather *when*. The computer does not care how you organize your code. The computer does care which things the computer does in which order. You should delete[] queue when you no longer need queue any more.

Comment: @user253751 I didnt put any of my objects here cos it wasnt relevant to the question i was asking. I wanted to know where in the class it would go, but i got my answer. Thanks for commenting anyway

Comment: @Kbreezy15 I still think "where" is the wrong question to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You should at least implement the delete operator in the destructor of the Queue class.

```cpp
class Queue
{
  public:
    ~Queue() 
    {
      delete[] queue;
    }
};
```

This changes if you start using a container instead of a simple array. You could also use a smart pointer to which will delete the array for you when it goes out of scope.

As mentioned by @mestkon please make sure your copy and move constructors are in line with the method you choose.

Comment: Also delete or mention copy/move semantics if you are suggesting this. Anything else will lead to broken code